# How to Convert Date 20211115 to 15-Nov-2021 in python

Tags: python, string

I have Date as `20211115 (YYYYMMDD)`, need to convert this to `11-Nov-2021` in python.
Please let me know the suggestions/answers for this.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that [you are expected to do research before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). It is very easy to answer this question using any search engine. I can [literally copy and paste your question title](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+Convert+Date+20211115+to+15-Nov-2021+in+python) and get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your date in YYYYmmdd format

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = "20211115"
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m%d")
date_time = date_object.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
print("date:",date_time)
```

output : `15-Nov-2021`

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you so much for the solution

Comment: Great. Please accept answer as correct. So it helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

The key is `strftime()`

```
timestamp = 1528797322
date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

print("Date time object:", date_time)

d = date_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print("Output 2:", d)   

d = date_time.strftime("%d %b, %Y")
print("Output 3:", d)

d = date_time.strftime("%d %B, %Y")
print("Output 4:", d)

d = date_time.strftime("%I%p")
print("Output 5:", d)
```

When you run the program, the output will be:

```
Date time object: 2018-06-12 09:55:22
Output 2: 06/12/2018, 09:55:22
Output 3: 12 Jun, 2018
Output 4: 12 June, 2018
Output 5: 09AM
```

%b  Abbreviated month name -> Jan, Feb, ..., Dec

%B  Full month name. January, February,...

[Referance](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)